# What does if [-f file]; mean?

Tags: bash

I have an if statement in a bash file:

```
if [ -f bin/post_compile ]; then
    echo "-----> Running post-compile hook"
    chmod +x bin/post_compile
    sub-env bin/post_compile
fi
```

what does the `-f` mean?

Comment: `help test | grep -- -f`

Comment: `[something]` is equivalent to `test something`. As @Cyrus says, lookup `test`, by typing `help test`.

Comment: Why the down-vote, the question is clear. It may be that we think the answer is obvious, but we should not down-vote for being “stupid” (not knowing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file exists and is a regular file.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

your statement in English:

If the file "/bin/post_compile" exists and is a regular file then:

1. Print message
2. Make the file executable
3. Execute the file using `sub-env`

end if (`fi`)